# URL Rewriting in Asp.net 4.0 not working on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am doing URL rewriting by registering routes and its working on my local machine(Windows 7).

But when I deploy the application to a dedicated server(Windows Server 2008 and II7), it says Resource not found when I hit the URL that is mapped to my page.

Following is the path that is being mapped:

```
routeCollection.MapPageRoute("School", "{pageid}", "~/PublicProfile.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the route so there's something before the pageId token, for example:

```
routeCollection.MapPageRoute("School", "PublicProfile/{pageid}", "~/PublicProfile.aspx");
```

Comment: Graham, thanks for the reply, but even this is not working and even this worked, I could not use this.
I have to implement the URL to show a public profile like: www.mydomain.com/yoururl